# Lose files in My Dual boot system?

Tags: 11.10, windows, dual-boot, files

I have installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 both 32bit as dual boot.

1. The problem I'm facing now is that I loose the data which store while I'm in Ubuntu. The data that I stored while I'm in Windows are kept well.
2. A new version of problem had to be faced today, The files *I deleted when I was in Ubuntu was available on Windows but I could not delete them from Windows* (I guess files were readable).

Please can anyone tell me the reason for this problem and how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You may have to find out more about your dual boot system to answer this question. In particular, it's likely that your boot disk has multiple partitions, at least one that's NTFS for Windows and one that's ext2/3/4 for Ubuntu.

When you boot Ubuntu, you won't see **see** (mount) the NTFS partition without some explicit actions (if I remember correctly). If you boot Windows, you can't mount an ext2/3/4 partition.

So, are you sure that you're mounting the NTFS partition? Try `mount` and `fdisk -l`.
Once you know you're mounting the right partition, then you must mount it read/write (rw).

Comment: I could not solve the problem of loosing files , but after several reboots i was able to delete the files.

Comment: as you said my partition are consist with both NTFS and ext3.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT hybernate Windows when switching to Ubuntu, but shutdown it completely.

In fact, Windows 7 restores the previous version of the files you have modified on the NTFS partition from Ubuntu when turning it on after hybernation/sleeping.